# How can i setState for color change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I already have the condition, but i need to set the state, if i setColor on the if method, give me error- Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

State:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState();
```

Map:

```
 {data.map((doc) => {
    let verificacao = "";

    if (doc.status === "Não Necessário") {
      verificacao = "Proxima Verificação:";
      setColor(true)

    } else if (doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme") {
      verificacao = "Data:";
      setColor(false)

    } else {
      console.log("ERRO");
    }

    return (
```

The span i want to change the color:

```
   <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className={color ? "red" : "green"}>
                    {doc.status}
                  </span>
                  <span className="data-status">{verificacao}</span>
                  {JSON.stringify(
                    doc.dateVerificado
                      .toDate()
                      .toISOString()
                      .replace(/T.*/, "")
                      .split("-")
                      .reverse()
                      .join("-")
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
```

Full Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import ManutencaoDataService from 
"../../Services/ManutecaoDataService";
import "./ManutencaoInfo.css";

const ManutencaoInfo = ({ getDataId }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [color, setColor] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {

  getData();
  return () => {
   setData([]);
 };
}, []);

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await ManutencaoDataService.getAllData();
  console.log(data.docs);
  setData(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
};

const deleteHandler = async (id) => {
  await ManutencaoDataService.deleteData(id);
  getData();
 };


return (
<>
  <div className=" container mb-2">
    <Button variant="dark edit" onClick={getData}>
      Atualizar Lista
    </Button>
  </div>

  {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(books, undefined, 2)}</pre>} */}

  {data.map((doc) => {
    let verificacao = "";

    if (doc.status === "Não Necessário") {
      verificacao = "Proxima Verificação:";
      setColor(true)
     
    } else if (doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme") {
      verificacao = "Data:";
      setColor(false)
     
    } else {
      console.log("ERRO");
    }

    return (
      <div key={doc.id} className="container-principal">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row relatorio">
            <div className="col">
              <div className="departamento">
                <h3>{doc.departamentos}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row detalhes">
            <div className="col">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className="identificacao">Equipamento: 
                </span>
                  {doc.equipamentos}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className="identificacao">Responsável: 
               </span>
                  {doc.responsaveis}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className="codigo">{doc.codigos.codigo} 
                </span>
                  <span className="tipo">{doc.tipo}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col ">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className="identificacao">Data Manutenção: 
                </span>
                  {JSON.stringify(
                    doc.dateManutencao
                      .toDate()
                      .toISOString()
                      .replace(/T.*/, "")
                      .split("-")
                      .reverse()
                      .join("-")
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className={color ? "red" : "green"}>
                    {doc.status}
                  </span>
                  <span className="data-status">{verificacao}</span>
                  {JSON.stringify(
                    doc.dateVerificado
                      .toDate()
                      .toISOString()
                      .replace(/T.*/, "")
                      .split("-")
                      .reverse()
                      .join("-")
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">{doc.codigos.observacoes} 
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row botoes">
            <div className="col">
              <span className="botao-editar">
                <Button
                  variant="secondary"
                  className="edit"
                  onClick={(e) => getDataId(doc.id)}
                >
                  Editar
                </Button>
              </span>
              <span className="botao-apagar">
                <Button
                  variant="danger"
                  className="delete"
                  onClick={(e) => deleteHandler(doc.id)}
                >
                  Apagar
                </Button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</>
  );
 };

  export default ManutencaoInfo;
```

Comment: Please write the complete code.

Comment: where are you setting the colour?

Comment: Im setting on the if method, but give me the error - Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: you can directly compare and set color class in span. like className={classNames({red: doc.status === "Não Necessário", green:doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme" })}

Comment: The `{data.map((doc)` - this indicates that the statements following it are executed multiple times (once for each `doc`). For each element in the `data` array - why is the same single `color` being set/reset? Don't you need each element to be either `red` or `green` based on that individual element's `status`?

Comment: your code doesn't need color state to be maintained

Comment: doc.status === "Não Necessário" i need to be red, and if doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme" i need to be green

Comment: You cannot call state updates directly inside a React render method or a function component. It is what that causes the `Too many updates` error. State updates should be inside either an event listener or a `useEffect` or a `Promise` callback.

Comment: The problem is you're changing state inside your render code. Changing state causes a re-render, which causes a state change, which causes a re-render, etc etc

Comment: Setting a single state variable inside a map function is nonsense anyway. Just use `className={doc.status === "Não Necessário" ? "red" : "green"}`

Comment: A better way is to prepare the data before rendering it so you can make your JSX more readable. The date stuff for instance should happen outside your JSX, and you don't need to stringify the result of `.join()` anyway since it's already a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using state, I would recommend using doc's status property for using the correct CSS class like this:

```
    <span className={doc.status === "Não Necessário" ? "red" : "green"}>
        {doc.status}
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import ManutencaoDataService from 
"../../Services/ManutecaoDataService";
import "./ManutencaoInfo.css";
import classNames from 'classnames';

const ManutencaoInfo = ({ getDataId }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]); 

 useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await ManutencaoDataService.getAllData();
  console.log(data.docs);
  setData(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
}

return (
<>
   ...

  {data.map((doc) => {
    return (
      <div key={doc.id} className="container-principal">
        <div className="container">
           ...
          <div className="row detalhes">
            ...
            <div className="col ">
               ...
              <div className="row">
                <div className="pontos">
                  <span className={classNames({red: doc.status === "Não Necessário", green:doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme" })}>
                    {doc.status}
                  </span>
                  <span className="data-status">{
 doc.status === "Não Necessário" ? "Proxima Verificação:" : doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme" ? "Data:" :""
}</span>
                 ....
                </div>
              </div>
               ....
            </div>
          </div>
           ...
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</>
  );
 };

  export default ManutencaoInfo;
```

create a new component which renders inside the map function, it will be better to maintain

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it with introducing state variable.
You can just use local variable in your function like this:

```
// Remove this state
// const [color, setColor] = useState();

{data.map((doc) => {
    let verificacao = "";
    let color; // add this var

    if (doc.status === "Não Necessário") {
      verificacao = "Proxima Verificação:";
      color = 'red' // changed
    } else if (doc.status === "Verificado e Conforme") {
      verificacao = "Data:";
      color = 'green' // changed
    } else {
      console.log("ERRO");
    }

    return (
       // ...
       <span className={color}> {/* changed */}
          {doc.status}
       </span>
       // ...
    )
```